# Ubuntu Logical Volume full but total file size does not match volume size

Tags: 22.04, lvm

I'm quite new to Linux / Ubuntu and have ended up in an interesting situation.

I created a VM with our hosting provided and assigned a disk of 15GB, after a while I wanted to extend the disk so I added another 15GB so that the total is now 30GB.

I use LVM and followed the instructions to extend the PV, the VG and the LV.

When I run `df -H` the output looks like this:

```bash
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              206M  2.1M  204M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   30G   30G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              1.1G     0  1.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.1G  265M  1.7G  14% /boot
overlay                             30G   30G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/14bf6b5fe4e4cbf18de4f119e72b856a4b2a12344400d70607e046a5700bf71d/merged
overlay                             30G   30G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/53fc9df182ab526cad1c6ad6f013d106132255e4b97f4054fa011f0add8b962e/merged
overlay                             30G   30G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fb07d9b0321d527ae2a81d140e32342f4ca106973266d915a8bef34d0137788a/merged
overlay                             30G   30G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4bb38aeb3fb507c4587293887b523bc2868c3750189c34a0fa930c3f8491a158/merged
overlay                             30G   30G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e4b1beda87ba3d6319ecce901f38ebc29ce286be747faba68eeb23ca5a0140f6/merged
overlay                             30G   30G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3be80b13cfb94f5a0825f2d08a3e6cfa8c5478467df2559d6dca8b6e1dc18c80/merged
overlay                             30G   30G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/68e0d290fe02d325221b48b5a9c01c6fa1c3cf62bd82504c5260a62d4d65a238/merged
overlay                             30G   30G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e3228f804d3e37373db3d17f9f15ce3d44bbaa05cdceac48d75420584b7bd490/merged
tmpfs                              206M  4.1k  206M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Looks to me as if I manged to extend `/dev/mapper/ubunti--vg-ubuntu--lv` which is nice.

As you can see, the Use% indicates that 100% of the space is used so I wanted to clean up stuff. I've been using `ncdu` and this command `du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"` to see what files that are taking up the space.

In both cases the total space sums up to around 15GB, here is the output of `du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"`:

```
3.3G    /usr
206M    /home
6.8G    /var
2.0M    /run
252M    /boot
5.6M    /etc
1.3G    /snap
2.9G    /swap.img
du: cannot access '/proc/4032530/task/4032530/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/4032530/task/4032530/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/4032530/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/4032530/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
15G     /
15G     total
```

As you can see the total size of the files is 15GB but the disc says that is has 30GB filled up.

What I'm I missing here and how can I find out why the disk is reported as full when only 15GB is used?

Cheers!

UPDATE:
After a while I decided to restart the machine to see if this have any impact.

`du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"` still outputs:

```
3.3G    /usr
206M    /home
6.8G    /var
1.9M    /run
252M    /boot
5.6M    /etc
1.3G    /snap
2.9G    /swap.img
du: cannot access '/proc/3263/task/3263/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3263/task/3263/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3263/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3263/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
15G     /
15G     total
```

But now the indicated usage `df -H` looks similar:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              206M  2.0M  204M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   30G   12G   17G  41% /
tmpfs                              1.1G     0  1.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.1G  265M  1.7G  14% /boot
overlay                             30G   12G   17G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/53fc9df182ab526cad1c6ad6f013d106132255e4b97f4054fa011f0add8b962e/merged
overlay                             30G   12G   17G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e4b1beda87ba3d6319ecce901f38ebc29ce286be747faba68eeb23ca5a0140f6/merged
overlay                             30G   12G   17G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/14bf6b5fe4e4cbf18de4f119e72b856a4b2a12344400d70607e046a5700bf71d/merged
overlay                             30G   12G   17G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/68e0d290fe02d325221b48b5a9c01c6fa1c3cf62bd82504c5260a62d4d65a238/merged
overlay                             30G   12G   17G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e3228f804d3e37373db3d17f9f15ce3d44bbaa05cdceac48d75420584b7bd490/merged
overlay                             30G   12G   17G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3be80b13cfb94f5a0825f2d08a3e6cfa8c5478467df2559d6dca8b6e1dc18c80/merged
overlay                             30G   12G   17G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4bb38aeb3fb507c4587293887b523bc2868c3750189c34a0fa930c3f8491a158/merged
overlay                             30G   12G   17G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fb07d9b0321d527ae2a81d140e32342f4ca106973266d915a8bef34d0137788a/merged
tmpfs                              206M  4.1k  206M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Still don't understand what happened before the restart of the machine.

Could it be that a restart was required for the mount of the new space to work?